# Smint plugin with Bootstrap, targeting list elements in nav

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Smint in order to auto-scroll down my one-page site when navigation links are clicked. I have the following in my HEAD section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="/js/smint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery('.nav').smint({
            'scrollSpeed' : 1000
        });
    });
</script>`
```

My nav bar contains:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#" id="sTop">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s1">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s2">Case Study</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s3">Contact</a></li>
</ul>`
```

and the id of the li items in my nav bar match the classes of sections in my body, like so:

```
<div class="s3"><h1>Contact Us</h1></div>
```

According to the instructions in Smint this is set up correctly - but when I click the links in my nav bar, I get

```
TypeError: $(...).position(...) is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:8000/js/smint.js
Line: 40
```

In order to get it to work, I can take the A link out of the list and just put it in the 'nav' element, but this breaks my nav menu.

I've tried every combination i can think of, obviously it's not targeting the li element within the 'nav' class.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit Benka - backticks didn't seem to be working for me? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the same code as yours on a JSFiddle, based on the SMINT demo page, and this seems to work. Please test this and tell me what you get !
http://jsfiddle.net/fvJcU/

I just wrote :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="#" id="sTop">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s1">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s2">Case Study</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="s3">Contact</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="section sTop">
    <h1>Demo page</h1>
</div>

<div class="section s1">
    <h1>Services</h1>
</div>

<div class="section s2">
    <h1>Case study</h1>
</div>

<div class="section s3">
    <h1>Contact</h1>
</div>
```

and the js :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.nav').smint({
        'scrollSpeed' : 1000
    });
});
```

If this works, check again your code, and if can can't find where the problem is please paste your exact code into a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you! That works - it's because I didn't have all the div classes in my html - I was just testing the 's3' at first as this was furthest down. Thanks again